# Xcode Leakage Tool NSXPCConnection?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What does that mean in the Xcode Leakage Tool?
I don't have any experience with this problem. I have a SpriteKit Scene and i am changing a property with a button in SwiftUI while the animation is happening.

**[NSXPCConnection remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler:]**

Comment: Add some code, please.

Comment: I have a similar question, but without answers yet: What does this Memory Leak mean in SpriteKit with SwiftUI?